# Get current user on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wordpress for the creation of an education site, for the discussion between instructor and student I use buddypress messaging and the better message plugin shortcode

I integrate the shortcode in one of the php files of my theme
the shortcode requires using the user id in this way user_id="" exemple :

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[bp_better_messages_pm_button text="Private Message" subject="Have a question to you" message="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." target="_self" class="extra-class" fast_start="0" url_only="0" user_id="3"]' ); ?>`

I would like to put the id of the user who is in the url example: [www.example.com/user-public-account/1/](http://www.example.com/user-public-account/1/)

how to do ?

Comment: You can parse the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with '/' and then put 1 index of parsed URL user_id="<?php $userid ?>"

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what i have to do

Comment: Try get_current_user_id()

Comment: Do you want to send current logged user or the ID we are sending in the URL?

Comment: ID we see in url so user can send message to user id in url

Comment: $urlParams = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$userid = $urlParams[1];

then this $userid you can use user_id="'+$userid+'"

Comment: @AnthonyBird i tried but i get error on the website

Comment: <?php 
$urlParams = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); $userid = end($urlParams);
echo do_shortcode( '[bp_better_messages_pm_button text="Private Message" subject="Have a question to you" message="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." target="_self" class="extra-class" fast_start="0" url_only="0" user_id="'+$userid+'"]' ); ?>

Comment: @SonuSindhu thank you i copy past this code but it didn't work, the button that should appear with this shortcode has disappeared

Comment: can you debug and see what you are getting in urlParams and userid

Comment: @SonuSindhu i activated debugging mode but i see nothing, there isn't error just the page keep loading

Comment: try to print this $urlParams & exit;

Comment: can you please tell me where to do this?

Comment: after that $urlParams = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Comment: @SonuSindhu nothing happened keep loading

Answer (score 0):

You can use - [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/)

Example:

```
<?php 
$cuser_id = get_current_user_id(); 
echo do_shortcode( '[bp_better_messages_pm_button text="Private Message" subject="Have a question to you" message="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." target="_self" class="extra-class" fast_start="0" url_only="0" user_id="'.$cuser_id.'"]' );
?>
```

**EDIT**
i see full discussion now - @SonuSindhu is right
its just that he used JS way of appending a variable meaning pluses instead of dots (PHP) on that param inside the shortcode

```
<?php
$urlParams = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$userid = end($urlParams);
echo do_shortcode( '[bp_better_messages_pm_button text="Private Message" subject="Have a question to you" message="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." target="_self" class="extra-class" fast_start="0" url_only="0" user_id="'.$userid.'"]' );
?>
```

Edit v2
( you need to be logged in to view the data print)

```
$urlParams = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$userid = end($urlParams);

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<pre style="z-index: 999; position: relative; background: #f9f9f9; direction: ltr; text-align: left;"> NAME:'."<br>";
    print_r($userid);
    echo '</pre>'."<br>";
}

echo do_shortcode( '[bp_better_messages_pm_button text="Private Message" subject="Have a question to you" message="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." target="_self" class="extra-class" fast_start="0" url_only="0" user_id="'.$userid.'"]' );
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response i tried to do it wih get_current_user_id() i hadn't get an error but nothing is shown, knowing that if the user id is not found the button(shortcode} will not work

Comment: You are getting your user id - thats why i edited to include @SonuSindhu response - are you using that second version with someone id in the URL?

what type of response are you supposed to get? can u share a link maybe / or better explain so i could help?

Comment: when i specify the user id like in the question, a button of sending a message is appear but when i tried to get the user id with the function the button diseppeard so it mean that the user id is not found

Comment: ok.. we need to debug it a bit.. 1st - can you share a link? 2nd.. can you temporarily add an echo before the "do shortcode" so that we make sure you are getting that id - see edit ver 2 example

Comment: btw, where are you seeing the instructions for the shortcode? got a link?

Comment: i'm getting it on BP BETTER MESSAGE PLUGIN , echo to print the shortcode ?

Comment: Ohh its the instructions inside the plugin? or in some external support page I can also read? yes, add the "print" - don't worry, only logged in users see that - were trying to see if you getting the ID - so visit the URL u mentioned that includes the ID as a parameter